# why sec:authorize doesn't work?

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security, authorization, taglib, spring-3

I have a JSF 2 page based on Facelets and use Spring Security 3 behind the application. When I put some tags like this within my page:

```
<sec:authorize  access="hasRole('SS')" >
<h:outputText value="X" /></sec:authorize>
```

the X will display at runtime anyway. The auto completion feature of eclipse work correctly to show the "sec:" tags and their properties at programming time. what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have you got:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

at the top of the file?

Also, you need `use-expressions="true"` in the http tag in securityBeans.xml. Doing this means that any old style `access="ROLE_BLAH"` tags in securityBeans or wherever also need to change to use expressions.